# How to make nested checkboxes in Antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Is there a way to create nested checkboxes in Antd (React UI library), like in the picture below?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlzqC.png)

Comment: Use TreeSelect with ```multiple```

Comment: https://ant.design/components/tree-select/#components-tree-select-demo-checkable

Answer (score 0):

Use Ant Design's Tree component to make a checkable tree that is a nested checkbox:
https://ant.design/components/tree/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).